# Can the input tag's name attribute simply be an integer?

Tags: html

Are the names of input tags allowed to simply be integers?

```
<input type="text" name="34" />
```

Just asking in case I were a lazy programmer. Or if I have a ton of arbitrary fields and it's not important what they are named.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the [`name` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-name-INPUT) is declared as taking CNAME value, which means any string of characters, without imposing constraints. HTML5 does not change this, except by disallowing the empty string; [its definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/attributes-common-to-form-controls.html#attr-fe-name) explicitly says: “Any non-empty value for name is allowed”.

People sometimes confuse the `name` attribute with the `id` attribute, upon which there are various constraints depending on HTML version (e.g., some versions forbid a value that starts with a digit).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they can. I wouldn't recommend it, but there's nothing wrong with using a number as a `name` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

No. Using integer is valid, yet it will be converted into a string.

> The content attribute is the attribute as you set it from the content (the HTML code) and you can set it or get it via element.setAttribute() or element.getAttribute(). The content attribute is **always a string** even when the expected value should be an integer. For example, to set an  element's maxlength to 42 using the content attribute, you have to call setAttribute("maxlength", "42") on that element.

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes

Answer (score 0):

It's valid in HTML5, but I'd avoid it. However, your code is still *not* valid HTML5 because of the self-closing tag. It should be:

```
<input type="text" name="34">
```

Comment: [I know it's not necessary, but I don't think it's wrong.](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/syntax.html#syntax-start-tag) Habits are hard to break... just consider it syntactic sugar!

Comment: “Self-closing tags” are allowed in HTML5 (and required in it when using the XHTML syntax). Ref.: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#start-tags

Comment: My bad, I thought it was not allowed unless using XHTML syntax.